# Display number of Input fields based on the value in database column

Tags: javascript, php

I have a database table with column name `qty` that holds an `int`.Now i want to display as many input fields as the value in `qty`.
So far i haved tried this using iavascript code . Here is my javascript code .

```
$(function() {

  var input = $(<input 'type'="text" />);
  var newFields = $('');

  $('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
    var n = this.value || 0;
    if (n+1) {
      if (n > newFields.length) {
        addFields(n);
      } else {
        removeFields(n);
      }
    }
  });

  function addFields(n) {
    for (i = newFields.length; i < n; i++) {
      var newInput = input.clone();
      newFields = newFields.add(newInput);
      newInput.appendTo('#newFields');
    }
  }

  function removeFields(n) {
    var removeField = newFields.slice(n).remove();
    newFields = newFields.not(removeField);
  } 
});
```

Comment: What you have try so far?

Comment: what you have done so far, show us some code

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. SO is not a code-service website. So kindly provide us what code have you done and we would be glad to help you on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the value in the textfield(hidden)
**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="quantitycount" value="4" />
<div class="textboxarea"></div>
```

**Jquery:**
Get the textbox value

```
var quantitycount=jQuery('#quantitycount').val();
var txthtml='';
for(var txtcount=0;txtcount<quantitycount;txtcount++){
 txthtml+='<input type="text" id="txtbox[]" value="" />';
}
jQuery('.textboxarea').html(txthtml);
```

You can use entry control loops to loop for number of times

Now we can see number of textbox as per need, Just the value from db and store that in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
foreach($qty as $qt){
    echo '<input type="text">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To append the text fields you need a wrapper on your html form

use some wrapper as mentioned by @Rajesh: and append your text-fields to that wrapper as shown below

```
$('#qty').bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        var n = this.value || 0;

          if (n >0) {
           for(var x=0;x<n;x++){
            $('#textboxarea').append('<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/>');
          } 
      });
```

similarly you can write your own logic to remove the text-fields also using jquery